# Best practice to handle multiple documents in QMdiArea?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qmainwindow, qmdiarea

I need to design and develop a kind of graphics piece of software, which can edit customized files containing graphical elements, etc.

I expect the piece of software to contain many documents thanks to the `QMdiArea` which is actually my central widget inside of my `QMainWindow`.

For each document, I will need both a `QGraphicsView` and a `QGraphicsScene` as well, since they work together.

Now, my question is, should I inherit `QGraphicsView` with a protected/private member to its own `QGraphicsScene`, or should I create a class which inherits `QWidget` and handles instances of `QGraphicsView` / `QGraphicsScene` ?

Or is there any solution left that I didn't think about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I don't think you need a QWidget to manage the QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. With that in mind, the "best practice" is typically to avoid subclassing if possible. Eventually you might have to subclass QGraphicsView (if you want to change its default functionality), but nothing in your question implies that you need to right now. Also note that there is a function `QGraphicsView::scene()` that returns the view's current scene, so there is no need to make the scene a member (it already is).

If you ever need to access a particular view or scene, you can do something like this:

```
MainWindow::onActionClearActiveWindow() // just an example
{
    QMdiArea *myMdiArea = static_cast<QMdiArea*>(centralWidget());
    QGraphicsView *activeView = static_cast<QGraphicsView*>(myMdiArea->widget());
    QGraphicsScene *activeScene = activeView->scene();
    activeScene->clear();
}
```

See also [`QMdiArea::subWindowList()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmdiarea.html#subWindowList) which returns a list of all the sub windows.

Comment: But the `scene` member of the `QGraphicsView` is set to null, isn't it? That is why I was thinking about subclassing the whole stuff and therefore create customised scene objects and the like. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: The `scene` member is null when you first construct a QGraphicsView, but you could just do `view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene)`. That will create a scene for the view, and afterwards you can get a pointer to that scene by calling `view->scene()`.

Comment: Anthony, I have another question: I will subclass `QGraphicsScene` so I will give it some custom behaviour, moreover I have to handle a collection of items. Shall I keep using `QGraphicsScene` / `QGraphicsView` or is it better to handle a class that encapsulates in attributes both of them?

Comment: Yes definitely keeping QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView! That's exactly what they are for. I think it is better to use them and keep them separate, rather than make a class to handle both the scene and view behavior. I think subclassing QGraphicsScene is quite normal, by the way.

Comment: So, you think that I should subclass `QGraphicsScene` and therefore add attributes into it - e.g. wether the document has been saved or not - don't you? I am pleased by the idea but I am definitely looking for the best solution.

Lastly I've subclassed `QGraphicsView` so I draw a surrounding rectangle without adding in to the `QGraphicsScene`, and that is why I wanted to do. What do you think about these practices?

Comment: I think we're getting a little off topic here but I'll send you an email shortly.